# I'm unable to remove postgresql 9.3 after installing it

Tags: software-installation, postgresql

I installed Postgresql 9.3 for Ubuntu 14.04 trusty using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-9.3 libpq-dev
```

I wanted to remove postgresql and instead install 9.2 so I ran this command

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-9.3 libpq-dev
```

This yields the error:

```
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

Running `sudo -i`,`echo $PATH` yields this output:

```
/opt/ree/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

#### Regression

I've tried this command to purge it from existence but I keep getting the same error:

```
sudo dpkg --purge postgresql-9.3
```

I've looked on some forums but I haven't found the error messages that I am receiving.

I've also looked into said directores and `/usr/local/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin` exist.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do `sudo -i`, enter your username's password, do `echo $PATH`, then do `exit`. Post the output from the command `echo $PATH` to your question.

Comment: Search for different messages like the part "not found in PATH or not executable". The first results I see is http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1942520 and gives plenty of possibilities to try. Please also include your tries as regression in your question and/or answer. For your understand, the issue is not that /usr/sbin etcetera paths do not exist, but that the installation can't find the helper applications `ldconfig` and `start-stop-daemon`.

Comment: Thanks Pro Backup. This removed the problem I was having. I had to use this command PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin sudo apt-get -f install

Answer (score 3):

Try to include the missing directories in your path before running the apt-get.

Like:

```
$ PATH=$(PATH):/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
$ sudo apt-get remove postgresql-client-9.3
```

Note: this PATH setting will be lost after reboot. The save this setting permanently place it in your shell its rc file, for example when using BASH shell: `$ nano .bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it from the repositories, you could try to uninstall it trough apt-get and not dpkg:

```
sudo apt-get remove posgresql-client-9.3
```

Comment: Hey darent thanks for the reply but no luck. I still get the same error message. :\